# Find border image of QMainWindow programmatically

Tags: qt

I set a border image on my `QMainWindow` using a style sheet:

```
QMainWindow
{
    border-image: url(:/metal_background);
}
```

In my program, there are several widgets with transparent background colors that sit on top of the main window. However when I drag and drop them, they look bad because they end up taking the system background color.

What I would like to do is get the brush(?) used to draw the mainwindow background, and use it to paint the child widget while it's being moved. I've tried:

```
QWidget* widget;
QMainWindow* mainWindow;
QList<QWidget*> widgets = qApp->topLevelWidgets();
foreach(widget, widgets)
{
    if(widget->objectName() == "mainWindow") // name is OK
        break;
}
mainWindow = static_cast<QMainWindow*>(widget);
qDebug() << mainWindow->objectName();
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(),
    mainWindow->palette().brush(mainWindow->backgroundRole()));
this->setPalette(palette);
this->repaint();
```

but it gives the background color/gradient, not the image. Am I doing something wrong, or is there another/better way to get the image?

Comment: AFAIR, you cannot get style sheets info from the `QWidget` palette in Qt. I think that the best you can do is to apply same style sheets to your child widgets or just propagate your main window`s style sheet to children.